# Integral representation formula for convex

Tags: convexity, convex-geometry, integral-transforms, integral-geometry

For $u \in \mathbb{S}^{d-1} \subset \mathbb{R}^d$, it is easy to show that:
\begin{equation}
u=c_d \int_{\mathbb{S^{d-1}}} \xi \mathbb{1}_{\left\{x \cdot u >0 \right\}}(\xi) \ \rm{d}\sigma_{d-1}(\xi)
\end{equation}
where  $\sigma_{d-1}$ is the uniform mesure on $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$. Because of symetries, one can prove this just for a specific vector, for example the first one of the $\mathbb{R}^d$ basis and a short computation does the trick.

Now, if $K$ is a convex compact whose interior contains $0$, and $u \in \partial K$, the knowledge of $\mathbb{S}^{d-1} \ni \xi \mapsto \mathbb{1}_{\left\{x \cdot u >0 \right\}}(\xi)$ is enough to reconstruct $u$.

**My question is**: is there the same kind of integral representation formula in this case too, i. e, $u \in \partial K \subset \mathbb{R}^d$,
\begin{equation}
u=\tilde{c}_{K} \int_{\mathbb{S^{d-1}}} \xi \mathbb{1}_{\left\{x \cdot u >0 \right\}}(\xi) \ \rm{d}\rho_K(\xi)
\end{equation}
where  $\rho_K$ is a mesure on $\mathbb{S}^{d-1}$ depending of $K$.

Comment: What's $x$? Should it be $\xi$?

Comment: @Deane Yang. Yes, if you like. Here $\mathbb{1}_{\left\{x \cdot u >0 \right\}}(\xi)$ stands for $\mathbb{1}_{\left\{x \in \mathbb{S}^{d-1} \ :\ x \cdot u >0 \right\}}(\xi)$, so $\mathbb{1}_{\left\{x \cdot u >0 \right\}}(\xi)=1$ if $u \cdot \xi >0$ and $0$ else.

Comment: OK. Understood.